# Use Android application as http proxy

Tags: android, proxy

I want to proxy traffic from an iPhone (or whatever) via my Android device and inspect the http traffic. First of all, is there any such appliation? (my device is not rooted)

Otherwise, I'm thinking of building it, but unsure if there is any problems with it?
You guys know of anything of the top of your head? Opening a server socket should be fine. Then acting as a proxy and dumping all traffic to logfile or similar?

Input appreciated.

Comment: If you want a simple source code from a real source code see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13439582/391668